# how pipes will be created in java programs

Tags: java

Actually in my program two pipes are opening , i don't know why they are opening . I want to close those but i don't know can any one suggest. 
Code where files are created.

```
while(true)
{
    //frequency is -1 for the first time before req is received from netstorm


    clientSocket.setSoTimeout((int)socketTimeOut);

    try
    {
        Thread.sleep(10000);

        // this is block if there is no line feed(\n) or a carriage return ('\r')

        strRecvLine = br.readLine();//here files are opening
        Thread.sleep(10000);

        if(strRecvLine == null)
        {

             return CONNECTION_CLOSED;
        }

    }
    catch(SocketTimeoutException e)
    {

        return INIT_MONITOR;
    }
    catch(SocketException e)
    {
        cmonLog.debugLog(className, "tcpRecv", "", "", "Socket exception. Test run may be over, Socket: " + clientSocket.toString());
      return CONNECTION_CLOSED;
    }
```

opened files

lsof -p 16178 | grep "pipe"
java    16178 cm0n  241r  FIFO                0,8      0t0 58898374 pipe
java    16178 cm0n  242w  FIFO                0,8      0t0 58898374 pipe

Comment: How about just closing the resources after use, e.g. the `br` which seems to be `BufferedReader`? It’s perfectly legal for the system to use pipes for local connections. As long as you close all resources properly after use they should disappear accordingly.

Comment: Those files are created when socket time out exception comes , so i added br.close in socket time out catch block,but still problem exists i am unable to get where problem exists and which resource using those files